# Creating classes to validate user login and database connection

Tags: java

Ok, I have a quick few question about some classes that I created. I created a manager and QueryManager class to do the heavy lifting in terms of validating user and establishing a DB connection. In the manager class, I receive an error (please see code, as I have the error documented there on the CachedRowSet). If I comment out that section and run the program, it runs and compiles fine and with a pop up box that says no valid user, but I have no DB connection. Can any look at my code to see any logic errors or if I am calling something incorrectly? I believe I am on the right path, so any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
package abaApplication;

        import java.awt.BorderLayout;
        import java.awt.EventQueue;

        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;
        import java.awt.Color;

        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.ImageIcon;



        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;

        public class MainPage extends JFrame {

            //private DBConnnection dBConnection;



            //public final static DefaultDBConnection dBConnection = new DefaultDBConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/abaapplication");
            private JPanel contentPane;
            private JTextField jtfUserName;
            private JPasswordField jpwfPassword;

            //private ResultSet rs;

            private final HomeScreen homeScreen = new HomeScreen();
            //private final MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
            public static final int  UNAUTHORIZEDUSER = -1;
            public static final int REGULARUSER = 1;
            public static final int ADMINUSER = 2;
            public static final int SUPERUSER = 3;
            private int loggedInRole = UNAUTHORIZEDUSER;
            private ActionListener callbackListener;
            private final SignUpPage signUpPage = new SignUpPage();
            private final ForgotUserNamePassword forgotUserNamePassword = new ForgotUserNamePassword();
            //private int loginStatus;

            /**
             * Launch the application.
             */


            public static void main(String[] args) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            MainPage frame = new MainPage();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * Create the frame.
             */
            public MainPage() {

                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setBounds(100, 100, 801, 527);
                contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                setContentPane(contentPane);
                contentPane.setLayout(null);

                JLabel jlblUserName = new JLabel("Username:");
                jlblUserName.setBounds(273, 175, 77, 16);
                contentPane.add(jlblUserName);

                jtfUserName = new JTextField();
                jtfUserName.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                jtfUserName.setColumns(10);
                jtfUserName.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                jtfUserName.setBounds(362, 170, 156, 26);
                contentPane.add(jtfUserName);

                JLabel jlblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
                jlblPassword.setBounds(273, 214, 77, 16);
                contentPane.add(jlblPassword);

                jpwfPassword = new JPasswordField();
                jpwfPassword.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                jpwfPassword.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                jpwfPassword.setBounds(362, 209, 156, 26);
                contentPane.add(jpwfPassword);

                JButton jbtnSignUp = new JButton("Sign Up");
                jbtnSignUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        MainPage.this.signUpPage.setVisible(true);
                        //signUpPage.setVisible(true);

                    }
                });
                jbtnSignUp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                jbtnSignUp.setBounds(298, 248, 92, 29);
                contentPane.add(jbtnSignUp);

                JButton jbtnLogin = new JButton("Login");
                jbtnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



                                userLogin(e);

                    }
                });
                jbtnLogin.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                jbtnLogin.setBounds(408, 248, 92, 29);
                contentPane.add(jbtnLogin);

                JButton jbtnForgotUserNamePassword = new JButton("Forgot Username/Password?");
                jbtnForgotUserNamePassword.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        MainPage.this.forgotUserNamePassword.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
                jbtnForgotUserNamePassword.setOpaque(false);
                jbtnForgotUserNamePassword.setForeground(new Color(0, 102, 255));
                jbtnForgotUserNamePassword.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                jbtnForgotUserNamePassword.setBorderPainted(false);
                jbtnForgotUserNamePassword.setBounds(290, 290, 228, 29);
                contentPane.add(jbtnForgotUserNamePassword);

                JLabel jlblBackGroundImage = new JLabel("");
                jlblBackGroundImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Justyn Bell\\Desktop\\abaApplicationImages\\Law-library2.jpg"));
                jlblBackGroundImage.setBounds(0, 0, 801, 527);
                contentPane.add(jlblBackGroundImage);
            }



            //void InitializeDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
                //try {
                    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                    //System.out.println("Driver loaded");

                    //Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/abaapplication", "root", "Sitekeyjdb2287");
                    // PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(Queries.getQuery("UserLogin"));
                    //pst.setString(2, "UserName");
                    //pst.setString(3, "Password");
                    //System.out.println("Database connected");
                    //query1=UPDATE user  SET name = ? WHERE id = ?
                    //PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement( Queries.getQuery("login") );
                    //statement.setString();
                    //statement.setInt();


                    //PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                //} catch (SQLException e) {

                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "We're sorry, there seems to be something wrong with the database connection");
                //}
            //}


             void userLogin(ActionEvent e) {
                String UserName = this.jtfUserName.getText();
                char [] Password = this.jpwfPassword.getPassword();

                if(UserName.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User name is a required field");
                }
                else if(Password.length <= 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password is a required field and cannot be left empty");
                }
                else {

                     resetFields();

                    int loginStatus = Manager.validateLogin(UserName, Password);

                    if (loginStatus == UNAUTHORIZEDUSER) {
                        //Helper.showMessage("Invalid credentials, please try again");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid user");
                    }
                    else {
                        this.loggedInRole = loginStatus;
                        if(this.callbackListener != null){
                            this.setVisible(false);
                            this.callbackListener.actionPerformed(e);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

                //}

                    //InitializeDB();


            //}



            void addActionListener(ActionListener callbackListener) {

                this.callbackListener = callbackListener;
            }

            void resetFields() {

                this.jtfUserName.setText("");
                this.jpwfPassword.setText("");
            }

            public int getLoggedInRole() {

                return loggedInRole;
            }

        }


    package abaApplication;

    public class Manager {

        public static int validateLogin(String UserName, char[] Password) {

            int role = MainPage.UNAUTHORIZEDUSER;

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE userName=? AND password=?";
            //String sql = "Login";
            String[] preStatementArray = new String[] { UserName, new String(Password) };
            //String[] param = new String[] { UserName, new String(Password) };

            //query1=UPDATE user  SET name = ? WHERE id = ?
            //PreparedSatement statement = c.prepareStatement( Queries.getQuery("query1") );
            //statement.setString();
            //statement.setInt();

            //ERROR ON THIS LINE SAYING I CANNOT ACCESS MAKE A STATIC REFERENCE TO A NON STATIC MEMBER!!
            javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet crs = QueryManager.executeQuery(sql, preStatementArray);

            try {
                if (! crs.next()) {
                    // not found record which is false
                    return role;
                }

                // found record which is true for debugging purpose
                System.out.println("firstName: " + crs.getString("firstName"));
                System.out.println("lastName: " + crs.getString("lastName"));
                System.out.println("userName: " + crs.getString("userName"));
                System.out.println("password: " + crs.getString("password"));
                System.out.println("email: " + crs.getString("email"));
                System.out.println("address: " + crs.getString("address"));
                System.out.println("city: " + crs.getString("city"));
                System.out.println("state: " + crs.getString("state"));
                System.out.println("zipCode: " + crs.getString("zipCode"));
                System.out.println("homePhone: " + crs.getString("homePhone"));
                System.out.println("cellPhone: " + crs.getString("cellPhone"));
                System.out.println("role: " + crs.getString("role"));

                role = crs.getInt("role");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                //log(ex);
            }

            return role;
        }
        /**
         * @param args
         */

    }


package abaApplication;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class QueryManager {//QUERY MANAGER BASED UPON INSTRUCTORS SQLDBLAYER;

    private static final String MySQL = null;
    //private static final Connection Connection = null;
    //public String[] URL = {"jdbc:mysql://localhost/abaapplication", "root", "Sitekeyjdb2287"};
    //public String[] URL = {"jdbc:mysql://localhost/abaapplication", "root", "root"};
    private static String sqlEngineType = "MySQL";
    private String serverName;
    private int port;
    private String database;
    //private String UserName = "";
    private String UserName;
    private String Password;
    //private String Password = "";

    //public QueryManager(String [] URL, String UserName, String Password) {
        //this.URL = URL;
        //this.UserName = UserName;
        //this.Password = Password;


    //}
    //public QueryManager(String sqlEngineType, String database) {

        //this(sqlEngineType, "", database, "", "");
    //}

    public QueryManager(String sqlEngineType, String serverName, String database, String UserName, String Password) {

        this(sqlEngineType, serverName, 3306, database, UserName, Password);
    }

    public QueryManager(String sqlEngineType, String serverName, int port, String database, String UserName, String Password) {

        this.sqlEngineType = sqlEngineType;
        this.serverName = serverName;
        this.port = port;
        this.database = database;
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public String getDatabaseDriverType(){
        return this.sqlEngineType;
    }
    public Connection getConnection() {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            if (sqlEngineType == MySQL) {

                // 1: Load the java jdbc
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                System.out.println("Driver connected");
                // 2: Establish connections
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + this.serverName + ":" + this.port + "/" + this.database, this.UserName, this.Password);
                System.out.println("Database connected");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.errorLog(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;

    }

    public boolean isConnectable() {

        Connection con = this.getConnection();
        if (con == null)
            return false;
        else {
            try {
                con.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public CachedRowSet executeQuery(String sql) {

        return this.executeQuery(sql, null);
    }

    public CachedRowSet executeQuery(String sql, String[] param) {

        CachedRowSet crs = null;

        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();

            ResultSet rs = null;

            if (param == null) {
                // 3: Create a statement / preparedStatement
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                // 4: Execute statement
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            }
            else {
                // 3: Create a statement / preparedStatement
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                for (int i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
                    stmt.setObject(i + 1, param[i]);
                }

                // 4: Execute statement
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            }

            crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
            crs.populate(rs);

            conn.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.errorLog(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return crs;
    }

    public int executeUpdate(String sql) {

        return this.executeUpdate(sql, null);
    }

    public int executeUpdate(String sql, String[] param) {

        int rowCount = -1;
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();

            if (param == null) {
                // 3: Create a statement / preparedStatement
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                // 4: Execute statement
                rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
            else {
                // 3: Create a statement / preparedStatement
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                for (int i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
                    stmt.setObject(i + 1, param[i]);
                }

                // 4: Execute statement
                rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            conn.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.errorLog(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return rowCount;
    }

    public int executeScalar(String sql) {

        return this.executeScalar(sql, null);
    }

    public int executeScalar(String sql, String[] preStatementArray) {

        int total = 0;
        CachedRowSet crs = executeQuery(sql, preStatementArray);
        if (crs != null) {
            try {
                if (crs.next()) {
                    total = Integer.parseInt(crs.getString(1));
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                this.errorLog(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            crs.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            this.errorLog(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return total;
    }

    private void errorLog(String msg) {

        System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error cause is you try to invoke non-static method `public CachedRowSet executeQuery(String sql, String[] param)` in static method.
There are several way to fix it:

1. add extra parameter to `validateLogin` method of `Manager` class.

   > public static int validateLogin(String UserName, char[] Password, QueryManager QueryManager)
2. <strike>Modify inner class `Manager`, so it could invoke the method of `QueryManager`.</strike>

<strike>For example:</strike>

```
public class Manager {
    public static int validateLogin(String UserName, char[] Password) {
        int role = MainPage.UNAUTHORIZEDUSER;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE userName=? AND password=?";
        String[] preStatementArray = new String[] { UserName, new String(Password) };
        javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet crs = executeQuery(sql, preStatementArray);
        //...
    }
}
```

### Update in 4/20

After reading your code again. I notice class `Manager` is not inside `QueryManger`, so 2nd way doesn't work.
The program have to `new QueryManager` before accessing it, For example: add following code to `MainPage` class.

```
private QueryManager queryManager;
private QueryManager getQueryManager() {
    if (queryManager == null) {
        queryManager = QueryManager(QueryManager.sqlEngineType, "serverName", "database", 
                                    "UserName", "Password");
    }
    return queryManager;
}
```

Comment: I get these first part of my question. Invoking a non-static method. The IDE informed me of that. I was also curious about  the DB Connection part also. It's not picking up a DB connection, so I wanted to ensure that I did not over look something in the QueryManager class.